# Finding non-zero indexes in a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an numpy array as follows:

```
np.array([
         [1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,   0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0,   1, 0]
        ])
```

Can anyone suggest the fastest way to obtain a 1-d array of indexes, where for each index there is at least one row of the array with an object at that index with a value > 0? So for the above array, the desired output is (it doesn't matter what the data type is i.e. list vs array vs series etc):

```
[0, 2, 3]
```

Please let me know if the above is unclear.  Currently, in my real usecase (below) I am starting with a dataframe, converting to series, turning to a numpy array, getting non-zero indexes, getting columns at those indexes.  However, I suspect a single operation on the dataframe (following conversion to a numpy array) would be faster that the `iterrows()` approach:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
                   [1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0,   0, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0,   1, 0]
                  ], 
                  columns = ['c1', 'c2, 'c3', 'c4', 'c5'], 
                  index = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3'])
set1 = set()
#This is what I would like to replace by going np.some_np_function(df1.to_numpy())
for protein, row in df1.iterrows():  
    non_zero_indexes = list(row.to_numpy().nonzero()[0])
    columns_with_positive = [p for i,p in enumerate(row.index) if i in non_zero_indexes]
    set1.update(columns_with_positive)
```

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = np.nonzero((a!=0).any(axis=0))[0]
```

Output: `array([0, 2, 3])`

With your dataframe:

```
s = df1.ne(0).any()
s.index[s]
```

Output:

```
Index(['c1', 'c3', 'c4'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: much quicker, thanks!